# How to improve the accuracy on this ios app that uses a coreml model

Tags: ios, pixel, mnist, coreml

I am trying to build an app that uses a keras, mnist trained model as the backend that recognises digits in the app.
Here is the app:

https://github.com/LOLIPOP-INTELLIGENCE/iOS-coreml

Try to run the app and see the results
I just need help to improve the accuracy in the app
Try digits like 9, 6 and 1
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That question is extremely broad. Plus you're not making it easy to look at the code. I suggest you compute the precision and recall for all the digits to see how well the model works on each digit.

Comment: Ok I will try that!